# Alternatives in JavaScript Callback Functions and How To Use Them

Tags: javascript, json, dom-events

I know the orientation in Stack Overflow is ask what you want and does not demonstrate how you would like it to be done, but I really do not know how to ask it in a better way and I'm not a Javascript expert... So... Let's go!

Let's imagine that we have the following Javascript functions with their respective outputs...

```
function func_a(param_a, param_b, param_c) {
    alert(param_a);
    alert(param_b);
    alert(param_c);
}

function func_b(func_to_run) {

    // Will call "func_a" HERE!
    func_to_run("a", "b", "c");
}

func_b(func_a);

// a
// b
// c
```

My questions are:

Is there a correct and/or better way to pass parameters to the function "func_a" when we pass it as argument of function "func_b"?

How can I pass parameters to the function "func_a" in the function "func_b" call? Below I'll give you a **hypothetical** example...

```
function func_a(param_a, param_b, param_c) {
    alert(param_a);
    alert(param_b);
    alert(param_c);
}

function func_b(func_to_run) {
    func_b_param = "z";

    // Will call "func_a" HERE!
    func_to_run(value_from_func_b_call, value_from_func_b_call, func_b_param);
}

// Third parameter deliberately empty!
func_b(func_a("a", "b", ));

// a
// b
// z
```

I do not know if I explained it clearly! If there is any doubt or suggestion of improvement please tell me!

Comment: What is `func_to_run`? Are you trying to pass a function reference and function parameters which correspond to the function to be called with those parameters?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes! Exactly! From what I understand so far does not seem like a good idea! Thank you! =D

Comment: @Brian Tompsett Thanks for the improvements in the question! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
function func_a(param_a, param_b, param_c) {
    alert(param_a);
    alert(param_b);
    alert(param_c);
}

function func_b(func_to_run, a, b) {
    func_b_param = "z";

    // Will call "func_a" HERE!
    func_to_run(a, b, func_b_param);
}


func_b(func_a, a, b);
```

Comment: Your answer is effective! It served me as guidance and information as to the path that I will follow! I believe that anything I can do need to be in that direction!

Comment: Glad to help you! Could you please accept this as answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the parameters to func_b:

```
function func_a(param_a, param_b, param_c) {
    alert(param_a);
    alert(param_b);
    alert(param_c);
}

function func_b(func_to_run, param1, param2) {
    func_b_param = "z";

    // Will call "func_a" HERE!
    func_to_run(param1, param2, func_b_param);
}

// Third parameter deliberately empty!
func_b(func_a, "a", "b");
```

Although that's a quick and dirty answer, if we had a better idea of what you are trying to achieve there might be a better answer. Especially with the new ES6 syntax and the spread operator.

Comment: I believe that anything I can do to be in that direction! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I pass parameters to the function "func_a" in the function
>   "func_b" call?

If interpret Question correctly you can pass an object to `func_b` as parameter where properties are set to 1) the function to call; 2) the parameters as an array passed to function to call; 3) the function to call within the function passed to call.

You can use `Reflect.apply()` to call the outer function to call, optionally setting `this` within the outer function; pass and array with first element being inner function to call at, for example, `func_b`, second element being parameters to call function with preceded by spread element.

At first parameter of outer function to call define a parameter representing the inner function to be called; at second parameter define rest parameters `func_a` representing the parameters passed to inner function to be called.

```js
function func_a(fn, ...args) {
  for (let arg of args) fn(arg)
}

function func_b(func_to_run) {
  // Will call "func_a" HERE!
  Reflect.apply(func_to_run.fn, null, [func_to_run.innerFn, ...func_to_run.args]);
}

func_b({
  fn: func_a,
  innerFn: alert,
  args: ["a", "b", "c"]
});
```

Comment: Very sophisticated! So we have more flexibility in other directions too! For now I'll consider a more obvious approach. Thank you!